# Why isn't there boost::intrusive::map?

Tags: c++, boost, dictionary, intrusive-containers

The boost documentation (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/intrusive.html) states that the intrusive containers are implemented for `list` (both single/double linked), `set` and `multiset`.
I couldn't find an implementation for the map. Is there any deeper reason for it, or is it just waiting to be implemented?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because a `map<Key, Value>` is actually `set<std::pair<Key const, Value>>` and Boost.Intrusive and Boost.MultiIndex sets allow you to use one of the value members as a key. In other words, there is no need for `map` if `find` can accept a comparable key, rather than the entire value to search for [which has been a long-standing unresolved issue with `std::map` and `std::set`](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3657.htm):

> The associative container lookup functions (find, lower_bound, upper_bound,
>   equal_range) only take an argument of key_type, requiring users to construct
>   (either implicitly or explicitly) an object of the key_type to do the lookup.
>   This may be expensive, e.g. constructing a large object to search in a set
>   when the comparator function only looks at one field of the object.  There
>   is strong desire among users to be able to search using other types which
>   are comparable with the key_type.

Comment: The option to call find without the value was the reason why I wanted to use map in the first place, thank you for the info.

Comment: @kovarex For this reason I recommend `boost::multi_index`, basically a `set` with correct `find` interface.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin. Where would the `boost::intrusive::hook` be in your example of `boost::intrusive::set<std::pair<Key const, Value>>`? Can it be contained in `Value`, or would one have to wrap `std::pair<Key const, Value>` in an object that also has a hook?

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin Also, will the `boost::intrusive::set<std::pair<Key const, Value>>` hold a weak reference to the set rather than `Value` or `Key`? So the `std::pair<Key const, Value>` objects will need to be held alive elsewhere?

Comment: @Clivest You may like to read up on how intrusive sets work and [what element requirements are](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/intrusive/set_multiset.html#intrusive.set_multiset.set_multiset_hooks).

Answer (score 4):

Since [version 1.59 Boost.Intrusive supports map-like associative containers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/intrusive/map_multimap.html). It's considerably more flexible than standard map-like containers as the programmer isn't forced to define any `std::pair` like structure to define `key_type` and `mapped_type`. A new option [key_of_value](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost/intrusive/key_of_value.html) is added to intrusive set interfaces defining which part of the value shall be considered as key_type and how to obtain it. This was done to simplify map-like usage when using Boost.Intrusive. Example code taken from Boost documentation:

```
#include <boost/static_assert.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_same.hpp>
#include <boost/intrusive/set.hpp>
#include <boost/intrusive/unordered_set.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

using namespace boost::intrusive;

class MyClass : public set_base_hook<>
              , public unordered_set_base_hook<>
{
   public:
   int first;
   explicit MyClass(int i) : first(i){}
};

//key_of_value function object, must:
//- be default constructible (and lightweight)
//- define the key type using "type"
//- define an operator() taking "const value_type&" and
//    returning "const type &"
struct first_int_is_key
{
   typedef int type;

   const type & operator()(const MyClass& v) const
   {  return v.first;  }
};

//Define omap like ordered and unordered classes 
typedef set< MyClass, key_of_value<first_int_is_key> > OrderedMap;
typedef unordered_set< MyClass, key_of_value<first_int_is_key> > UnorderedMap;

int main()
{
   BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT((boost::is_same<  OrderedMap::key_type, int>::value));
   BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT((boost::is_same<UnorderedMap::key_type, int>::value));

   //Create several MyClass objects, each one with a different value
   //and insert them into the omap
   std::vector<MyClass> values;
   for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)  values.push_back(MyClass(i));

   //Create ordered/unordered maps and insert values
   OrderedMap   omap(values.begin(), values.end());
   UnorderedMap::bucket_type buckets[100];
   UnorderedMap umap(values.begin(), values.end(), UnorderedMap::bucket_traits(buckets, 100));

   //Test each element using the key_type (int)
   for(int i = 0; i != 100; ++i){
      assert(omap.find(i) != omap.end());
      assert(umap.find(i) != umap.end());
      assert(omap.lower_bound(i) != omap.end());
      assert(++omap.lower_bound(i) == omap.upper_bound(i));
      assert(omap.equal_range(i).first != omap.equal_range(i).second);
      assert(umap.equal_range(i).first != umap.equal_range(i).second);
   }

   //Count and erase by key
   for(int i = 0; i != 100; ++i){
      assert(1 == omap.count(i));
      assert(1 == umap.count(i));
      assert(1 == omap.erase(i));
      assert(1 == umap.erase(i));
   }
   assert(omap.empty());
   assert(umap.empty());

   return 0;
}
```